# Why is AWS user-data HTTP endpoint incorrect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data, spinnaker

I'm trying to debug a Spinnaker pipeline that is not properly injecting my userdata to a Windows EC2 instance.  For testing, I launched one with a simple base64 encoded userdata script like this:

```
<powershell>
write-output "Running userdata-test script"
</powershell>
```

From within the instance when I query the userdata HTTP endpoint it returns this:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"X-aws-ec2-metadata-token" = $token} -Method GET -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data

powershell
----------
...
```

However, the log file shows that it did actually run my script.

```
2023/04/08 01:49:27Z: Begin user data script process.
2023/04/08 01:49:27Z: Unable to parse <persist> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2023/04/08 01:49:27Z: Sending telemetry bool: IsUserDataScheduledPerBoot
2023/04/08 01:49:27Z: Unregister the scheduled task to persist user data.
2023/04/08 01:49:31Z: Unable to parse <runAsLocalSystem> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2023/04/08 01:49:31Z: Unable to parse <script> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2023/04/08 01:49:31Z: Unable to parse <powershellArguments> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2023/04/08 01:49:31Z: <powershell> tag was provided.. running powershell content
2023/04/08 01:49:35Z: Message: The output from user data script: Running userdata-test script

2023/04/08 01:49:35Z: User data script completed.
```

Is this a bug in the HTTP endpoint?  Is there any other reliable method of seeing the true userdata?

Comment: Does it work as expected if you use `Invoke-WebRequest` instead?  This "helpful" parsing/reformatting behavior seems to be intentional in the design of `Invoke-RestMethod` and there doesn't appear to be a way to turn it off.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for the tip!  Apparently my original request was trying to be smart and returning an `XmlDocument`.  So I have can get the real response from the `.OuterXml` property.  If you want to make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of the Amazon EC2 Instance Metadata Service.

Version 1 allows you to directly access the metadata:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

[Version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/instance-metadata-v2-how-it-works.html) requires that you first retrieve a token, and then call the metadata service:

```
PS C:\> [string]$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds" = "21600"} -Method PUT -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token

PS C:\> Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"X-aws-ec2-metadata-token" = $token} -Method GET -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

Comparing this to your Question, it would appear that your code is missing the first line that sets the value of the `$token` variable.

Comment: I am setting the token, I just omitted that from the example for brevity.  Without a token, you would get empty response 401.

Comment: So are you saying that if you run the above two lines in PowerShell manually it returns the User Data, but when run in the User Data script it returns nothing? Please Edit your Question to show enough of a script so that we can try to reproduce your situation.